# Meteor user name based on userId

Tags: meteor

I am saving logged in userId with each record saved in my Meteor app collection as shown in the example below, yet I was wondering if there was any way in Meteor where I can retrieve user name based on the user saved id without have to make another query on the users collection? In Node.js / mongoose there was this Populate function, but I can't seem to find similar package / function in Meteor. So I was wondering if someone can help me by suggesting a resolution to this problem (if any). thanks

```
    var newInvoice = {
        customerid: $(e.target).find('[name=customer]').val(),
        userid: Meteor.userId(),
        //....more fields here
    }
    Meteor.call('saveInvoice', newInvoice, function(error, id){
        if(error)
            return alert(error.reason);
    });
```

Comment: Meteor.users.findOne({_id:Meteor.userId()}).username ? Or maybe Meteor.user().username?

Comment: @Sindis thanks but this is just a new query, which is the classic approach. I was hoping for a better Meteor solution as described in my question, for example as Mongoose > populate.

Comment: Meteor.users.find is query ok, but Meteor.user() doesn't make database call, it's an object available any time

Comment: @Sindis yes but I am not looking to get currently logged in user name, I am looking to get the name of userID in the previously saved document, make sense?